# Programming Open OSX System Preferences Extensions pane and anchor to Finder item

Tags: macos, synchronization, preferences, finder

I want to open the System Preferences pane and anchor to Extensions/Finder item by using these code:

```
    let url = URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.extensions?Extensions_FinderSync")!
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
```

But it just goes to the System preferences's home page, which seems to be an invalid URL, what's the correct URL?

Comment: There don't seem to be any available anchors in the Extensions prefpane, unfortunately

Comment: Is there any other way to do that? Such as Apple script?